# How to Upload image using retrofit 2

Tags: android, image-uploading, retrofit2

I am new to retrofit, I want to upload an image to server selected from the device gallery or image clicked from the camera intent. I googled and did not find a proper solution.

My server receives image/file as multipart/form-data. please help me in fulfilling my requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the code please and also your Uploading json format

Comment: @Nivedh I have not tried yet, but my data that i want to post to my REST api has a image, and two strings

Comment: @Nivedh I created a form in html that accepts a enctype='multipart/form-data', then my REST code executes and saves the image in my server folder and updates the path in my db.

Comment: Have you gone through https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server.
 I asked to post json because in retrofit 2 its not possible to upload image which is inside nested json tags . But if its outside it works fine

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution ,and it works

retrofit interface

```
        @Multipart
        @POST("api/v1/users/edit")
        Call<AccountInfo> editUserInfoAvatar(@Part("type") RequestBody type, @Part("file\"; filename=\"my_image.jpg") RequestBody file);
```

call method

```
public void sendAvatar(ImageItem avatar){
        File file=new File(avatar.path);
        RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), file);
        RequestBody typeBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "avatar");
        Call<AccountInfo> call = HttpManager.getHttpClient().editUserInfoAvatar(typeBody,fileBody);
call.enqueue(...);
```

}

hope it would help ,buddy

Comment: How will i send image from the device gallery?

Comment: it is the same logic